# Why can't I statically reference an inner class's static method on a generic class?

Tags: java, generics, static, inner-classes

Please go through the entire question to have complete idea.

First let the class `Box` is given as follows:-

```
public class Box <T>{
    private T t;

    public  void  set(T t){
        this.t  = t;
        System.out.println("value:\n");
        System.out.printf("%s", t.toString());
    }
    public T get() {
        return t;
    }
    static int retInt(){
        return 5;

    }
     public <U extends Number> void inspect(U u){
            System.out.println("T: " + t.getClass().getName());
            System.out.println("U: " + u.getClass().getName());
        }

}
```

Generic class `Util` as given below:-

```
public class Util<T>{
    private T t;

    //Generic method
    public  <K, V> boolean compare(Pair<K, V> p1, Pair<K, V> p2) {
        return p1.getKey().equals(p2.getKey()) &&
               p1.getValue().equals(p2.getValue());
    }

    /* Static generic or non-generic methods can be declared in generic class 
       but they can not make use of generic parameter type(as generics static    
       methods  using class type variable must know the type argument 
       (i.e value of type parameter); and knowledge of type argument is
       possible only when object of same generic class are instantiated  
       (meaning assigning value of generic type parameter <T> or better to 
       say declared object have it's type argument; for example 
       as in List<T> replace T with Integer,String, Float etc);
       but static method may be called without having 
       instance of class; so such declaration for static generic method are
       not allowed) here it is <T>;  like for example as shown below  

       public static int checkFun(T t){
          return 5;
       } // this generate compiler error complaining "can not make static
        //  reference to non-static type T".           
    */


    public static <K> boolean cmp(Box<K> b1, Box<K> b2){
        // implement comparator to compare but here 
        return true;
    }

    // Inner class Pair
    public class Pair <K, V> {
        private K key;
        private V value;

        // Generic constructor
        public Pair(K key, V value) {
            this.key = key;
            this.value = value;
        }

        public void setKey(K key) {
            int i = 6;
            if(i >4 || i<9);
            this.key = key;
        }

        public void setValue(V value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public K getKey(){
            return key;
        }

        public V getValue(){
            return value;
        }

    }

    public void main1() {           
        //The complete syntax for invoking this method would be:
        // <Integer, String>   new Util<T>().
        Pair<Integer, String> p1 = new Pair<Integer,String>(1, "apple");
        Pair<Integer, String> p2 = new Pair<Integer, String>(2, "pear");
        boolean same = compare(p1, p2);
        //boolean same = true;
        if(same)System.out.println("it is true: they are the same");
        else System.out.println("nah! they are not the same...");

        //boolean sm = compare();
    }

    public static void main  (String[] args) /*throws FileNotFoundException */{
        //new Util<Integer>(). main1();

        Util<Integer> util = new Util<>();
        util.main1();
    }  
}
```

Above code compiles and executes just fine, my discomfort lies here:

If we add `static` modifier to method

```
public <K, V> boolean compare(Pair<K, V> p1, Pair<K, V> p2)    -------(1)
// called in method main1()
```

and make it

```
public static <K, V> boolean compare(Pair<K, V> p1, Pair<K, V> p2)     -------(2)
```

then compiler will complain that **Cannot make a static reference to the non-static type Pair** whereas similar method

```
 public static <K> boolean cmp(Box<K> b1, Box<K> b2)    -------(3)
```

which is also static but doesn't complain. Even though we are not using type parameter `<T>` in both method `but`  a `big but` in method we are talking from `eq-1` the argument it uses is from inner class `Pair` (so reasoning of my ambiguity may be explained with reference to this feature).

But still; logically, I feel that adding modifier `static` to method in `eq-1` should not generate compile time error because wherever the method in `eq-2`  is called it will be responsibility of that method to call with correct argument to method in `eq-2` and it should be allowed to be called like a static method.

**Question:-**
What is the explanation for not using static modifier for the method:

```
public <K, V> boolean compare(Pair<K, V> p1, Pair<K, V> p2)
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason for this is the type parameter on the Util class and the inner class Pair is non-static. Because Pair is a non-static inner class, it can use the T type parameter of Util (even though in this case it does not). Therefore when Pair is used it is necessary to specify a T, either by accessing it within the context of a Util instance (where the T is implicitly available) or by qualifying by accessing it through a specific `Util<T>`, e.g. `Util<Integer>.Pair<String,Object>`. Another way to think of it is that the type of Pair depends on the type parameter of Util and `Util<String>.Pair<K,V>` is not compatible with `Util<Object>.Pair<K,V>`.

To keep the type parameter T on Util and keep Pair as a non-static inner class, you can change the signature of compare to

```
public static <T, K, V> boolean compare(Util<T>.Pair<K, V> p1, Util<T>.Pair<K, V> p2)
```

or

```
public static <K,V> boolean compare(Util<?>.Pair<K,V> p1, Util<?>.Pair<K,V> p2)
```

which is possible because the instantiation of T is not relevant to the body of the method.

As an alternative, since Pair does not refer to anything (non-static) inside of Util you can change the definition of Pair to be

```
public static class Pair <K, V> { /* ... */ }
```

Finally for completeness, if Util did not have a type parameter then

```
public static <K, V> boolean compare(Pair<K, V> p1, Pair<K, V> p2)
```

and

```
public class Pair<K, V> { /* ... */ }
```

would be just fine.

Comment: ,Thanks man.As I believe you covered almost all the part.I had a kind of solution to problem but the first explanation you gave to keep type parameter T on have partially removed my doubt. But still I am not able to get my head around compiler complain for not using static modifier. You said  quote **Therefore Pair must be used in a context where there is a particular T available** unquote. As I said in my question(And I believe, where I may be wrong ) that **T** information will be available while creating object of **Pair** class(here in method **main1()** which is non static).

Comment: as I said above calling method **main1()** requires argument(value) to type parameter so Object of class **Pair** will automatically have value of **T** , which object of class Pair may use(even though here they not using). So, please throw some light on the issue here so that my confusion is removed.

Comment: @zeal you're right that is a little unclear, I changed that sentence of the answer. Hope that it makes more sense now. I also added some notes about generic wildcards that was missing before.

Comment: Thanks Geoff, the edits(use of wildcard<?>) really helped in clearing the clouds of doubt and even the use of **Util<T>.** for prefixing **Pair<K, V>** make sense now.                                             Once again thank you very much.